# "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "flights" does not exist"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgres://kali:kali@localhost/mydb")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute ("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights;").fetchall()
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After i execute python , he send for me:
I do not know the reason
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "flights" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights
                                                  ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "list.py", line 13, in main
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1278, in execute
    clause, params or {}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 984, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1103, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1288, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1482, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "flights" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights
                                                  ^

[SQL: SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
root@ubuntu:~/lecture3# python3 list2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "flights" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights;
                                                  ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list2.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "list2.py", line 10, in main
    flights = db.execute ("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights;").fetchall()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1278, in execute
    clause, params or {}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 984, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1103, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1288, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1482, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "flights" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights;
                                                  ^

[SQL: SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I try change `"engine = create_engine("postgres://kali:kali@localhost/mydb")"` to `"engine = create_engine(os.getenv("postgres://kali:kali@localhost:5432/mydb"))"` and:

```
" AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins' "
```

Comment: postgres=# SELECT * FROM flights
postgres-# ;
 id |  origin  | destination | duration 
----+----------+-------------+----------
  2 | Shanghai | Paris       |      760
  3 | Istanbul | Tokyo       |      700
  4 | New York | Paris       |      435
  5 | Moscow   | Paris       |      245
  6 | Lima     | New York    |      455
  1 | New York | London      |      430
(6 rows) ------- This is a table on psql

Comment: you need to check if `flights` this table exist. or check you SQL syntax.

Comment: The `flights` table appears to be in a schema that is available when you run the SELECT from the psql prompt, but not when you try to execute it from your Python code. Confirm the schema in which the `flights` table resides, then have your Python query specify the schema, e.g., `SELECT ... FROM myschema.flights`

Answer (score -1):

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "flights" does not exist`
Means that you don't have a table by the name of(flights) in your database.

Create the table like this:
`CREATE TABLE flights(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, origin VARCHAR NOT NULL, destination VARCHAR NOT NULL, duration INTEGER NOT NULL);`
Then try running your application, it should work.